# How to I perfectly space & arranged a bunch of items? [iPad]

Tags: affinity-designer, ipad

I’ve got a bunch of circles that I want to have the same spacing between them how do perfectly arrange them? (I’m using the iPad version of Affinity Designer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all your circles.  Then in the transform tool (in the tool bar on the right), select Alignment Options:

[image]

Tap the last of the horizontal (or vertical) alignment options.  Then tap Auto:

[image]

Alternatively, deselect Auto and enter your desired width between each item:

[image]